# Carat Syntax in Kotlin Interfaces

Tags: generics, kotlin

May help to explain this just a bit.

Say I have an abstract class called Page that looks like so:

```
abstract class Page {
    abstract fun title() : String
}
```

And an interface called Book:

```
interface Book {
    fun write(page: Page)
    fun read(title: String) Page
}
```

My question is how can I use the carat generic syntax to specify that the methods must be used by derived instance of the Page class. Maybe like this:

```
interface Book<Page> {
    fun write(page: Page)
    fun read(title: String) : Page
}

class AdventureBookPage(val pageTitle: String, val content: String) : Page() {

    override fun title() : String {
        return title
    }
}

class AdventureBook : Book<AdventureBookPage> {
    override fun write(abp: AdventureBookPage) {
        // do writing ops
    }
    override fun read(title: String) : AdventureBookPage {
        // do read ops
    }
}
```

Am I misunderstanding how generics work here? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I misunderstanding how generics work here?

Yes, a little.

```
interface Book<Page> {
    fun write(page: Page)
    fun read(title: String) : Page
}
```

What you've essentially declared here is this:

```
interface Book<Foo> {
    fun write(page: Foo)
    fun read(title: String) : Foo
}
```

`Page` was just an identifier, representing any old type. You could make a `Book<String>`, a `Book<HttpClient>` or a `Book<ArrayList<String>>`. Ordinarily, rather than `Foo` or `Page`, the identifier `T` is used, standing for 'type'.

The fact that the identifier matches a type you've created yourself is only incidental.

What I suppose you were trying to declare was that a book is a collection of pages, or *anything more specialised* than a page. This is called a ['generic constraint'](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-constraints), and you would express that like so:

```
interface Book<T : Page> {
    fun write(page: T)
    fun read(title: String) : T
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was trying to do. Just couldn't pinpoint in the docs. 

Generic Constraints! Whodathunkit!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the kotlin constraints, specifically Upper bounds:

```
interface Book<T : Page> {
    fun write(page: T)
    fun read(title: String) : T
}
```

docs [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-constraints)

Comment: You may want to quote or summarize the relevant part in the off chance that link breaks.

Comment: @RuckusT-Boom I don't know how to do that, I saw other users done it

Comment: Just copy/paste (maybe rewrite) the relevant part of the page you refer to in your answer.

Comment: @RuckusT-Boom thanks! I found it! I edited the answer with the correct link